# Google map, On Zoom here Click

Tags: jquery, asp.net, google-maps

I have used a `google map` in my application.

And I want that whenever a User select the area and click on the Zoom here option there is `SidePane` it should hide that area and map should get `widen`.

Please see the `Zoom here Jquery code` and also the Side pane toggle. Any help would be appreciated.

```
J.selectedStore_changed = function () {
        $(".highlighted", this.b).removeClass("highlighted");
        var a = this, b = this.get("selectedStore");
        if (b) {
            this.m = b;
            this.b[r]("#store-" + b[D]())[x]("highlighted");
            this.c.directions && this.a[r](".directions-to").val(b.getDetails().title);
            var c = a.get("view").getInfoWindow().getContent(), e = $("<a/>").text("Directions")[p]("href", "#")[x]("action")[x]("directions"), i = $("<a/>").text("Zoom here")[p]("href", "#")[x]("action")[x]("zoomhere"), k = $("<a/>").text("")[p]("href", "#")[x]("action")[x]("streetview");
            e[z](function () {
                if ($('#panel').is(":visible") == false) {
                    $('#panel').animate({
                        width: 'toggle'
                    });
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        google.maps.event.trigger(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), "resize");
                    }, 250);
                }
                a.showDirections();
                return g;
            }
                );
            i[z](function () { a.get("view")[u]().setOptions({ center: b[j](), zoom: 16 }) }); k[z](function () { var c = a.get("view")[u]().getStreetView(); c.setPosition(b[j]()); c.setVisible(d) }); $(c)[G](e)[G](i)[G](k);
        }
    };
    J.hideDirections = function () { this.h = g; this.a.fadeOut(); this.d.fadeIn(); this.b.fadeIn(); this.l[F](f) };
    J.showDirections = function () { var a = this.get("selectedStore"); this.d.fadeOut(); this.b.fadeOut(); this.a[r](".directions-to").val(a.getDetails().title); this.a.fadeIn(); S(this); this.h = d }; function S(a) { if (a.k && a.m) { var b = a.a[r](".rendered-directions").empty(); a.t.route({ origin: a.k, destination: a.m[j](), travelMode: google[t].DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING }, function (c, e) { if (e == google[t].DirectionsStatus.OK) { var i = a.l; i.setPanel(b[0]); i[F](a.get("view")[u]()); i.setDirections(c) } }) } } J.featureFilter_changed = function () { T(this) }; function V() { this.b = [] } K.StaticDataFeed = V; V[C].setStores = function (a) { this.b = a; this.a ? this.a() : delete this.a }; V[C].getStores = function (a, b, c) { if (this.b[B]) { for (var e = [], i = 0, k; k = this.b[i]; i++) k.hasAllFeatures(b) && e[w](k); aa(a.getCenter(), e); c(e) } else { var y = this; this.a = function () { y.getStores(a, b, c) } } }; function aa(a, b) { b.sort(function (b, e) { return b.distanceTo(a) - e.distanceTo(a) }) };
```

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: I am not getting error, I want to integrate that functionality but I am not able to do so.

Comment: from where you got this code REF, example? or if you have jsfiddle link of your code?

Comment: OK, will give you the jsfiddle,its a js. http://jsfiddle.net/jv2ro0tb/

Comment: from where you get this javascript code? library? link? or you have written?

Comment: I got it from somewhere, It is for google map. I did not write this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59987/discussion-between-zeeshan-and-saba).